# JPQL update no work good

Tags: java, jpql

hello I have a small problem when you run a query when making an update me predefine some values ​​to 0 and the operation is not correct I have other 2 are the same and work well what I find strange because this gives that error I wanted to know from his point of view this can happen is my code

```
  public void crearHistorial(Equipo equipo) {
    historialDao.crearHistorial(equipo, login.getUsuario(), historial.getHorastd(), historial.getUbicacion());
    EntityManagerFactory emf
            = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("inventarioPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    equipo.setNumeroControl(historial.getUbicacion());
    equipoDAO.actualizarExpediente(equipo, login.getUsuario());
    abrirEquipo(equipoID);
    Query query = em.createQuery("UPDATE Historial c SET c.horasTrabajadas= c.horastd -" + expediente.getHorastotales() + " WHERE c.equipo.id=" + equipo.getId());
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    query.executeUpdate();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    JPAManager jpam = new JPAManager();
    listahist = jpam.ejecutarQuery("SELECT c FROM Historial c WHERE c.equipo.id=" + equipo.getId(), null, -1);
    for (Historial hist : listahist) {
        Query query2 = em.createQuery("UPDATE Equipo c SET c.horasmotor= c.horasmotor -" + hist.getHorasTrabajadas() + " WHERE c.id=" + expediente.getId());
        Query query3 = em.createQuery("UPDATE Equipo c SET c.horashrida= c.horashrida  -" + hist.getHorasTrabajadas() + " WHERE c.id=" + equipo.getId());
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        query2.executeUpdate();
        query3.executeUpdate();
        em.getTransaction().commit();

         Query query1 = em.createQuery("UPDATE Equipo c SET c.horastotales= c.horastotales  +" + hist.getHorasTrabajadas() + "WHERE c.id=" + equipo.getId());
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        query1.executeUpdate();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } }
```

query have problem is query1, query2 and query3 work good, horastotales and horasTrabajadas is atributte double .

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're saying since you didn't use any punctuation, but I think “gives that error” means you're getting an exception.  Edit your question and include that exception's entire stack trace (as code-formatted text, not as an image).  Without it, we have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: no have exceptions! my friend query1 run update no work fine so put horasTrabajas en 0.00 and no sum good.